# How to resolve inconsistent group protocol when connecting to AWS MSK cluster?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have setup an MSK cluster. I created the topics I need.

The problem is that when I try to setup the consumer I get

`Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: JoinGroup failed: Broker: Inconsistent group protocol`

The group is created

when I describe it I get

```
GROUP                                                                    COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY  STATE           #MEMBERS
hbgm_consumers_2                                                         b-2[...]:9092 (2) roundrobin           Stable          2
```

```
ConsumerConfig conf = new ConsumerConfig(new ClientConfig());
                conf.BootstrapServers = brokers;
                conf.GroupId = consumergroup;
                conf.SessionTimeoutMs = 30000;
                conf.EnableAutoCommit = false;
                PartitionAssignmentStrategy strategy = getAssignmentStrategy(priorityConfig);


                conf.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                conf.PartitionAssignmentStrategy = PartitionAssignmentStrategy.RoundRobin;
                conf.GroupId = consumergroup; // group name is correct


                consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, FileObject<string>>(conf).
                    SetKeyDeserializer(Confluent.Kafka.Deserializers.Utf8).
                    SetValueDeserializer(new FileObjectDeserializer<string>()).
                    Build();

                consumer.Subscribe(inputTopic);
```

Comment: The librdkafka client that's part of the dotnet client is that latest version of Kafka protocol. MSK is not running most recent Kafka...try downgrading your dependencies

Comment: I can find nothing that mentions version issues. Do you know of any docs which show version compatibility?

Comment: The "group protocol" has changed over several versions of Kafka. It's somewhat covered in the Kafka upgrade guide docs about what versions cause backwards incompatible changes